# How to merge 2 rows of a Python Data frame with same column id into one row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I want to merge the rows with similar column ids, there are multiple columns in the dataset approx 50. Now in one row with id="ABC", there are values in 25 columns and in another row with id="ABC" there are values in the rest 25 columns. I want to have only a single unique id with values in all 50 columns.
Basically, want to merge rows with duplicate ids.
But If there is no value in id column but there is a value in id2 or id3 then the row should not be deleted.

GIVEN DATAFRAME :

```
    id         value1  value2  value3   value4  id2    id3
    ABC        100                       ABD    AND    
    ABC                 101     UBC                    DND
    XYZ        200              ANF      BAC    ALC    BLC
    XYZ                 202
               200      300     QWE      RTY    FGH    IJK
                        501     UIO      JKL    QWR
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    id       value1    value2 value3  value4  id2   id3
    ABC        100       101    UBC     ABD   AND   DND
    XYZ        200       202    ANF     BAC   ALC   BLC
               200       300    QWE     RTY   FGH   IJK
                         501    UIO     JKL   QWR
```

There are around 50 different columns in the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do - `df.groupby('id').first()`. It will take the first non `nan` value in every column.

It may mess up your data if for the same id you have few records with different values in the same column.